# Using window.print() with blob

Tags: javascript, window, blob

I would like to get blob data from api and print it with window.print() (chrome)

I googled different solutions but nothing worked.
I tried the following code but the window opens without activating print.

```
objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
myWindow = window.open(objectUrl)
myWindow.print()
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share how you perform the api call? Maybe you just do not wait until the response is gathered.

Comment: I have an issue to open and print in chrome ,following simple example is not working `function printP(){var w = window.open("http://wikipedia.org"); w.print()}`